# Erro ao abrir H2 Database

Tags: java, h2database

Fui tentar abrir um arquivo H2 Database que não está corrompido e o H2 Database me retornou o seguinte erro:

```
Encryption error in file "C:/Users/Administrator/test.h2.db" [90049-189] 90049/90049 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Encryption error in file "C:/Users/Administrator/test.h2.db" [90049-189] 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) 
    at org.h2.store.FileStore.init(FileStore.java:203) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openFile(Database.java:533) 
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:328) 
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:288) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2464) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:672) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:269) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:263) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:65) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:175) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:153) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:136) 
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:149) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:143) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:448) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:329) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91) 
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:735) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.test(WebApp.java:893) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:221) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:170) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:133) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:89) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Sou novo em Java e gostaria de saber mais ou menos oq é esse erro...

Comment: Como está fazendo para tentar se conectar ao banco? Alguma informação está errada, como o algoritmo de encriptação ou usuário/senha

Comment: @BrunoCésar Se o usuário/senha tivesse errado não tinha q aparecer 'Wrong user name or password [28000-189] 28000/28000' ?

Comment: Me conecto pelo console do h2 database

Comment: Não, esse 28000 é quando usa autenticação comum, não da forma que está tentando

Comment: Então eu tenho q saber usuário/senha para entrar? Ou tem alguma coisa errada na formação da criptografia?